# Require a Defined Test Set In Java

Tags: java, testing, interface, junit5

As part of my integration tests, I have 5-6 "example" objects that are used to verify the various parts of the software come together correctly. For each of those example objects, I'd like to define a "standard set" of tests to run.

How do I enforce that those tests are always written? Is an interface defining the tests appropriate? Or is there a better way?

Comment: There is also an _abstract class_, and also just basic inheritance of a parent class.  You can have the parent class hold the logic and the sub-classes hold the data.